# Java - How to return PDF/Image from Spring Application as API response and process the content using JS/React?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot

In one of my Spring Boot and React application, I need to write an API that will send file name as input, and expect Java/Spring Boot will return the file content, and then show the content in a new tab of the browser. So I write the following code:

**FrontEnd API Request:**

```
let fileUrlResponse = await rest.fetchAttchment(fileName[0].fileName);
let data = fileUrlResponse.data;

let byteArray = new Uint8Array(data.length);
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    byteArray[i] = data.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;
}

let contentType = fileUrlResponse.headers['content-type'];
const file = new Blob([byteArray], { type: contentType });
const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
```

**In Controller:**

```
@GetMapping(value = ApiConstants.GET_FILE_VIEW)
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getView(@RequestParam("fileName") String fileName) throws CommonException {
    ResponseEntity<Resource> response = leaveAppAdminService.findFileContent(fileName);
    return response;
}
```

**In Service:**

```
public ResponseEntity<Resource> findFileContent( String fileName ) throws CommonException {
    try {
        String fileUrl = leaveAttachmentUploadPath;
        Path path = Paths.get(fileUrl + "/" + fileName);
        byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(fileBytes);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName);
        if( extension.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf") ) {
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
        }
        else if( extension.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg") || extension.equalsIgnoreCase("jpeg")) {
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
        }
        else if( extension.equalsIgnoreCase("png") ) {
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                 .contentLength(resource.contentLength())
                 .headers(headers).body(resource);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Exception occurred during execution of -> findExLeaveByUnit ", ex);
        log.info("Error info:{}", ex.getMessage());
        throw new CommonException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Response:**
Some screenshot of current responses are:

[image: Response Part 1]

[image: Response Part 2]

[image: Response Part 3]

**Problem:**
It export PDF without any content, I mean blank PDF!
Does anyone have any idea what's I miss or what is the proper way to return the content of a PDF or Image file as API response.

Initially I thought `byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(path)` or `ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(fileBytes)` generate wrong data, so I tried to export the PDF using the following code:

```
String filePath = "D:/test.pdf";
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
    fos.write(fileBytes);
    System.out.println("Byte array content written to file: " + filePath);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It export the PDF successfully with the data.
I also tried to the following code in FrontEnd side:

```
let data = fileUrlResponse.data;
const encoder = new TextEncoder();
const byteArray = encoder.encode(data);
const file = new Blob([byteArray], { type: contentType });
const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a very simplistic test where I have a class annotated with `@RestController` that just reads the file and writes it into `OutputStream` of `HttpServletResponse`. I invoked that API and simply wrote bytes that I received on disk as a file. I was able to open that file and was exact copy of a file that my API read and sent as a response. Here is the code:

```
@PutMapping
public void uploadDownloadTest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
            byte[] buff = readFile(...);
            response.getOutputStream().write(buff);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(TextUtils.getStacktrace(e));
    }
}
```

Note that I didn't even set any response headers that would inform client side what to expect (and that was on purpose for this particular test). Still, when I invoked this API from Java (using some Http client) I was able to get the info properly. I didn't try your API code though. I hope this helps. I am guessing that your problem is on your client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `BufferedInputStream` and the `BufferedOutputStream`. Use the `inputstream` to read your file `pdf/image` and then write the contents in the output stream where

```
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), BUFFER_SIZE)
```

`BUFFER_SIZE` is in bytes. You can use any appropriate amount `10kb` etc.

Answer (score 0):

try this one
the file path is file that contain all my files

```
    // to get files from server
@GetMapping(path = "/file/{fileName}")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getfile(
                                      @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {

        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(File_PATH +
                File.separator +
                fileName));
    String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName);
    if( extension.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf") ) {
        log.info("pdf");
        //headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
    }
    else if( extension.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg") || extension.equalsIgnoreCase("jpeg")) {
        log.info("IMAGE_JPEG");
        //headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    }
    else if( extension.equalsIgnoreCase("png") ) {
        log.info("IMAGE_PNG");
        //headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
    }

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    if( extension.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf") ) {
        log.info("pdf");
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
    }
    else if( extension.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg") || extension.equalsIgnoreCase("jpeg")) {
        log.info("IMAGE_JPEG");
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    }
    else if( extension.equalsIgnoreCase("png") ) {
        log.info("IMAGE_PNG");
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
    } else {
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    }
    //headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", fileName); to download file
        return new ResponseEntity<>(fileContent, headers, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```